# Different e-mail in my CV

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I have written my CV on StackOverflow and now I want that I could insert there an arbitrary e-mail address.

Why to do so?

I have two e-mail addresses associated with my SO account. The first (which appears in CV) is from my former employer and is defunct now. The second is just a technical mail account used for login purposes only. It looks not so smooth, may scary the potential employers out and may lose information due to strange filtering.

Additionally SO warns me that all the careers data will be overwritten if I link to another careers account. But I do not want to lose my fine CV just because of one tiny wrong e-mail address.

And yes, I do not want to link SO with a contact mail address. I'd prefer that it should be a freely editable text only, without mail address verification. If I write it wrong, I'm ready to take all the consequences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your email address will not be displayed publicly on your CV. We don't want you to get spam! Stack Overflow will use your email address to contact you, and we'll show it to employers when you send them a message.

If you still want to change the email address in your Jobs profile, you can go to the CV editor:

[image: How to find the CV editor]

Click "edit" on the personal details section:

[image: The personal details section]

From here you can change your email address, with a handy pop-up reminding you of what I just told you.

[image: Changing your email]

Comment: Thank you very much! What I did wrong - I went to the `https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/my_id` page and looked at `Linked Careers Account`. Thank you for the patience!

Comment: P.S. It did send me a confirmation e-mail! What if I simply ignore it?